# SQL Server "Application Intent=readonly" not working JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, sql-server-2012

Im am trying to hit the secondary node on a sql server 2012 DB using `"ApplicationIntent=readonly"` in the connection string.

It is still hitting the primary node, not sure why.

I'm using `sqljdbc4-4.0` jar

java JDBC call:

```
ResultSet results = null;
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
Connection conn = null;

String SQL_SERVER_DRIVER = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
Class.forName(SQL_SERVER_DRIVER);

String dbString = "jdbc:sqlserver://*****;applicationIntent=ReadOnly;databaseName=****;user=*****;password=****;";
    
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbString);
preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement("some_sql");

results = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Do you have a answer for this? We are also experiencing this problem

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to get it to work properly?

Answer (score 3):

You should connect to availability group listener (AGL) address(es). you can use below query to find availability group listener addresses:

```
select * from sys.availability_group_listener_ip_addresses
```

after you find the AGL address your jdbc connection string should be :

```
jdbc:sqlserver://[AGL-ADDRESS]:1433;databaseName=[DB_NAME];user=[username];password=[password];applicationIntent=ReadOnly
```